# Magento2 How can i create block on popup with product details?

Tags: magento2, custom-block, popup

I want to show product details on popup using controller.

**So how is it possible?**

```
$htmlCatInfo = $layout->createBlock(
                \Tigren\Ajaxcart\Block\BuildProductInfo::class,
                'ajax.buildproduct-info',
                ['data' => ['itemid' => $itemid]]
            )->setTemplate('Tigren_Ajaxcart::buildpopupcatinfo.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Any one can tell me how can I manage data .phtml to block

Answer (score 0):

In the block class you can load the product using the itemId data from repository  https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-product-id-sku-magento-2.html          and after that you can create the phtml content according to the output which you want to show..